# Change function that loads a font via loadFromFile() to loadFromMemory() in my resource class

Tags: c++, memory, resources, sfml

I have this resource class that holds my resources (just fonts) for me. I call initialise() to load the resources, then I do 
the normal program flow and before I exit the program I call cleanUp(). This is all working perfectly.

This is the code for the class. resources.h:

```
#ifndef __RESOURCES_H__
#define __RESOURCES_H__

#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Resources {
 public:
  Resources();
  bool initialise();
  void cleanUp();
  bool loadAllFonts();
  bool loadFont(std::string filename);
  sf::Font &getFont(std::string filename);

  const std::string myFont_;
  const std::string myOtherFont_;

 private:
  const std::string fontPath_;
  std::map<std::string, sf::Font*> fonts_;

};

#endif
```

resources.cpp:

```
#include "resources.h"

Resources::Resources() : 
  myFont_("./data/myFont.ttf"),
  myOtherFont_("./data/myOtherFont.ttf")
{
}

bool Resources::initialise() {
  if (loadAllFonts()) { return true; }
  return false;
}

void Resources::cleanUp() {
  std::map<std::string, sf::Font*>::iterator font_it;
  for (font_it = fonts_.begin(); font_it != fonts_.end(); font_it++) {
    delete font_it->second;
    font_it->second = NULL;
  }
  fonts_.clear();
}

bool Resources::loadAllFonts() {
  if (!loadFont(myFont_)) { return false; }
  if (!loadFont(myOtherFont_)) { return false; }
  return true;
}

bool Resources::loadFont(std::string filename) {
  if (fonts_.find(filename) != fonts_.end()) {
    return false;
  }
  sf::Font *font = new sf::Font();
  sf::err().rdbuf(NULL);
  if (!font->loadFromFile(filename)) {
    delete font;
    font = NULL;
    return false;
  }
  const_cast<sf::Texture&>(font->getTexture(8)).setSmooth(false);
  const_cast<sf::Texture&>(font->getTexture(12)).setSmooth(false);
  const_cast<sf::Texture&>(font->getTexture(16)).setSmooth(false);
  const_cast<sf::Texture&>(font->getTexture(24)).setSmooth(false);
  fonts_.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Font*>(filename, font));
  return true;
}

sf::Font &Resources::getFont(std::string filename) {
  return *(fonts_.find(filename)->second);
}
```

This was simple enough and went without problems. I just use the class like this:

```
int main() {
  //...

  Resources resources_;
  resources_.initialise();

  sf::Text testText("test text", resources_.getFont(resources_.myFont_), 25);

  // ... (program loop)

  resources_.cleanUp();

  return 0;
}
```

Now, what I want to do is the following:

In `Resources::loadFont()`, instead of loading a font from a file with `loadFromFile(filename)`, I want to load it from memory.

I know how loading a font from memory works. I simply convert a font file and fill an unsigned char array with the font data:

```
unsigned char myFontChar[] = {0x00,0x01, .......... ,0x00,0x30,0x4f,0x53,0x2f};
```

Then I load the font like this:

```
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromMemory(myFontChar, sizeof(myFontChar))) { return -1; }
```

This is working when I do it as demonstrated above, but I have no idea how I would go about adjusting the `Resources::loadFont()` function so that instead of loading the specified font from a file it loads it from memory (the unsigned char array).

Could you please help me and point me in the right direction?

I am not a pro, so this is hard for me, but I have some vague idea how to do it (in theory). I would apply the same principle that I currently have: Use an "identifier" so the std::map could be used. 
Instead of `std::map<std::string, sf::Font*>` I would have to use something that replaces the second parameter `sf::Font*`, but I don't know what that would be and how the `Resources::loadFont()` function would then look like.

I hope I explained it well enough and really really hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Your error handling would fit on http://thedailywtf.com/. If you fail to load the font you try to load it again? What makes you think it would work the second time? And you don't even check or report *why* you could not load the font.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry, copy paste error, fixed it!

Comment: Just to make sure: instead of loading fonts from files, you want to hardcode them into your program and load them from static memory? If so, why?

Comment: @Chaosed0 Yes, exactly, and there are actually several reasons. Amongst others, so I only have to ship the .exe, and I can make sure the font file is not replaced by another font file with the same name by the user (because my program depends on the exact fonts I have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not do this. It makes things less configurable and inflexible. Most users won't touch the directory a program resides in. On the flipside, if someone really, really wanted to change the font, they could still overwrite the portion of memory in your executable that contained the font. Assuming you do have a good reason for doing it, though, here's some ideas.

One way to do this is to simply initialize the `std::map` in your constructor, assigning whatever strings you want to your fonts:

```
bool Resources::loadAllFonts() {
  sf::Font *tempfont;

  tempfont = new sf::Font();
  if (!(tempfont->loadFromMemory(myFontMem)) { return false; }
  fonts_["myfont"] = tempfont;

  tempfont = new sf::Font();
  if (!(tempfont->loadFromMemory(myOtherFontMem)) { return false; }
  fonts_["myotherfont"] = tempfont;

  return true;
}
```

Later, you'll need to remember the strings you assigned.

However, the way I'd do it if you only have a few fonts is to store them in `Resources` as individual members and just convert the `getFont()` function into an if/else block:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class Resources {
 public:
    //...

 private:
  const std::string fontPath_;
  // Load these fonts in the constructor
  sf::Font myFont;
  sf::Font myOtherFont;

};

// ...

sf::Font &Resources::getFont(std::string fontname) {
   if(fontname == "myfont") {
       return myFont;
   } else if(fontname == "myotherfont") {
       return myOtherFont;
   } else {
       // Error somehow
   }
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted. I tested both suggestions and both work! I chose your second approach though because now I don't even need the `std::map` and `cleanUp()` and `loadFont()` anymore, I just have the `sf::Font`s as members and load them from memory in `initialise()`, and use your `getFont()` function (which I slightly changed) to return them. Thank you so much for this!!!